# edsdk c# pinvoke function EdsCreateMemoryStream has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, pinvoke, calling-convention, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm developing small photographical app, that supposed to work with Canon EDSDK api with EOS cameras. Everything worked fine with old dll's (from 2014) and with old cameras, Canon 1100D and 1200D. Recently I purchased succesor, model 1300D. Of course, old dll's (2014) didn't recognized new model of camera from 2016, and I couldn't connect to the camera.

So I replaced old dll's:
EDSDK.dll 
and
EdsImage.dll

with new ones, taken from last Canon EOS Utility ver.3, that works with Canon 1300D.

Now, my camera is recognized, on my main panel I can see the name of connected camera, Canon EOS 1300D.

But after replacing dll's, when I try to start live view from camera, I get this strange error message:

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'testApp!EDSDKLib.EDSDK::EdsCreateMemoryStream' has unbalanced the
>   stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not
>   match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
>   convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature

I will be very grateful for any help. i have lost a lot of time on this already. I don't have any ideas anymore and I don't know where shoud I search for an answers.

Thanks You all in advance.

Comment: Did you read the message and do what it suggests? We can't help because only you have code. And only you have the DLLs. And without source for the DLLs it will be hard. Have you asked vendor for help.

Answer (score 2):

Version 3.4 changed some parameters from `uint` to `ulong`.
Since you still use the old function definitions this is where the problem comes from.
Check the difference in the header files or the C# file that comes with the EDSDK.

I think these functions are the ones you need to change:

- EdsDownload
- EdsCreateMemoryStream
- EdsCreateMemoryStreamFromPointer
- EdsRead
- EdsWrite
- EdsSeek
- EdsGetPosition
- EdsGetLength
- EdsCopyData

Also note that the `DirectoryItemInfo` struct changed its `Size` field from uint to ulong.

In version 3.2 the `PictureStyleDesc` struct changed. The `uint SharpFineness` and `uint SharpThreshold` fields were added.